# Send response asynchronously in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, servlets, jackson, spring-boot

Need to add following functionality to my Spring Boot based REST application:

When a POST method is called, a long running process is started.  At regular intervals (every 5 seconds or so), I need to display a message in the browser to the user, until the process ends.

Note:  This method may not be just called from a browser.  Might be called in the future from a shell script.  The goal is to send response intermittently in the 'response body'.

I tried adding code such as this:

```
                    OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
                    os.write(msg.getBytes());
                    os.flush();
```

But got NullPointer exception while flushing.

How would I do this? Do I have to make an AJAX call or something like that?

Comment: is your 'long running process' started as different thread and response is committed immediately ?

Comment: No, it's not started as a different thread & response is not committed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here. The most fundamental is that HTTP isn't designed to send multiple responses to a single request. Secondly, blocking a request processing thread for the duration of a long-running process is likely to cause problems.

A better approach would be to send a response as soon as the long running process is initiated. This response would have a `202 Accepted` status code and a `Location` header that provides another URI that can be polled by the client to get information about the long-running tasks. For example: `Location: https://yourapi.example.com/tasks/123456`. It's then the client's responsibility to execute a `GET` requests against this tasks URI to obtain information about the progress of the long-running process.

Comment: Hi, I too need the same thing. I send a request to get the data of 10 parts. As soon as I retrieve 5 parts of data, I need to return to UI,Then after some time I need to send the remaining parts data. Is there any code snippet for this. Kindly share if exists.

Comment: What is this sort of API programming model called If one was to look up more information ?

Comment: For those who may find it useful. I found a github project which loosely does what this comment suggests: https://github.com/katezer/asynchronous-rest-api